# dynamic memory allocation in Fortran

Tags: fortran, computer-science

I need some help with allocating arrays dynamically.

I have an array whose size keeps changing at each step - I start with a row vector and add another row vector at each step of a cycle. I need to use this new array for further calculations.

I've been trying to declare the arrays as allocatable, and then allocate them within a do-loop, but I haven't been able to get it working properly.

I am still not very clear with what happens when you deallocate the memory for that particular array. If the data is lost, then to store it before deallocation, do I use another array? How do I specify the size of that array?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
! Program to generate a matrix whose rows are linearly independent vectors. 
! The elements of the matrix are either 1 or -1

   program trial

   implicit none 
   integer, parameter ::n=10,p=5   !where 'p' gives the no. of rows, & 'n' gives the no. of columns
   real(kind=8),dimension(p,n) ::z1 
! The array to be generated - this needs to be made allocatable
! I'll need the values of this array for further calculations, so should I store
! them in another array?

   integer::i,j,k,s1  !counters used
   real(kind=8),dimension(n)::x

   do i=1,p
15  call random_number(x) !generate random row vectors 
    z1(i,:)=x

! To make the array elements 1's and -1's
    do j=1,n
        if (z1(i,j).ge.0.5) then
            z1(i,j)=1.d0
!           write(*,*),z1(i,j)
        else
            z1(i,j)=-1.d0
!           write(*,*),z1(i,j)
        endif
    enddo

! Checking the output so far
    print*,'Z1'
    do k=1,i
        write(*,*)(z1(k,j),j=1,n)
    enddo

! To ckeck for linear independence, get the reduced row echelon form. Check the rows
! of the rref array, if any of the rows contains only zeros, the vectors are not
! linearly independent. Hence, regenerate that particular row of the array. 

! Check for linear independence as each row is added

    call to_rref(z1)
        do k=1,i
            s1=0
            do j=1,n
            if(z1(k,j)==0)then
                s1=s1+1
            endif
            if (s1==n) then
                print *,'THE VECTORS ARE NOT LINEARLY INDEPENDENT'
            goto 15
            endif
            enddo
        enddo

    do k=1,i
        write(*,*)(z1(k,j),j=1,n)
    enddo
   enddo

   end

! Subroutine for getting the reduced row echelon form 
subroutine to_rref(matrix)
    implicit none
    real, dimension(:,:), intent(inout) :: matrix

    integer :: pivot, norow, nocolumn
    integer :: r, i
    real, dimension(:), allocatable :: trow

    pivot = 1
    norow = size(matrix, 1)
    nocolumn = size(matrix, 2)

    allocate(trow(nocolumn))

    do r = 1, norow
       if ( nocolumn <= pivot ) exit
       i = r
       do while ( matrix(i, pivot) == 0 )
          i = i + 1
          if ( norow == i ) then
             i = r
             pivot = pivot + 1
             if ( nocolumn == pivot ) return
          end if
       end do
       trow = matrix(i, :)
       matrix(i, :) = matrix(r, :)
       matrix(r, :) = trow
       matrix(r, :) = matrix(r, :) / matrix(r, pivot)
       do i = 1, norow
          if ( i /= r ) matrix(i, :) = matrix(i, :) - matrix(r, :) * matrix(i, pivot) 
       end do
       pivot = pivot + 1
    end do
    deallocate(trow)
  end subroutine to_rref
```

Comment: The subroutine to_rref has an assumed shape argument, which means that in any scope where it is called it must have an explicit interface.  Such an interface does not exist in the main program.  Put the subroutine in a module or provide an explicit interface block.  Until you fix that your code is meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, when you deallocate memory you must regard it as no longer existent.   In Fortran 95 and earlier, if you wish to expand an array, you must copy the data to another array, deallocate the array, reallocate and copy the portion back.   Fortran 2003 provides an intrinsic procedure that simplifies the process: move_alloc.